# How do I add error bars based on a series?

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a Google Spreadsheet.

First sheet is a set of raw data for ratings of beers.

Then I have a pivot table on that data, showing beers grouped by brewery, with values for the countunique() of the beers from that brewery, the average() of the rating for beers from that brewery and the stddevp() for those ratings.

Then I have a bar chart showing the ratings by brewery.

I'd like to show error bars for each of the average rating columns - but when I edit the chart, under "advanced edit", "customization", "series", "AVERAGE of Rating", my only options for error bars are "none", "constant" and "percent". There's no option to base the error bars on another series from the pivot table, even if I include the series in the chart - that just gets me another series of bars.

How do I add error bars to my chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear Google Sheets is just not yet sufficiently sophisticated for what you would like. I think the closest I may be able to get to your requirement with the given tool is to stack three series, hide the base series and hint at the colours indicating a 'spread' by adding error bars of unit height to each series:

[image: WA4478 example]